# Pure Mage Viable w/Dragonborn DLC?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

Since most people consider pure mages not to be super viable in Vanilla Skyrim, with the new Masks how do Mages stand now in the Dragonborn DLC? Is it actually viable.

I actually like the idea of a Frost mage....but I know thats probably the weakest of the three?

Comment: fwiw pure mage is definitely feasible in vanilla skyrim.  You'll have to rely more on just destruction (and specifically 1 element) though.  I did just fine with a heavy mix of conjuration, illusion, and destruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "viability" in skyrim. You can simply outlevel almost any challenge in the game since enemies have a cap at which they no longer scale. Some builds are slower and less efficient but that doesn't make them unplayable. "Viablility" is a term that should be reserved for situations where you cannot use grinding to outlevel the enemy. If you do find it too difficult with your build just lower the difficulty a notch. Skyrim is meant to be played with whatever character you want, you shouldn't worry about "viability".